# \textsc on a path with decoration

Tags: tikz-decorations

**[Original question]**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}  
    \node [circle, draw=red, fill=red!30] (N1) at (0,0) {A};
  \node [circle, draw=red, fill=green!30] (N2) at (5,0) {B};
  \draw [red,->] [postaction={decoration={raise=3pt, text along path, text={|\textsc|Text||},text align=center}, decorate}] (N1.north) to [out=45,in=135] (N2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want `\textsc` works. Any help?

**[Updated]**

After CarLaTeX's answer, I got:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}  
    \node [circle, draw=red, fill=red!30] (N1) at (0,0) {A};
  \node [circle, draw=red, fill=green!30] (N2) at (5,0) {B};
  \draw [red,->] [postaction={decoration={raise=3pt, text along path, text={|\scshape|Text |\_| |+$\theta$|},text align=center}, decorate}] (N1.north) to [out=45,in=135] (N2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want `_` and `$\theta$` works.

Comment: I've also restored the original question; otherwise, the title is no more coherent with its text. However, for the future, I think it's better if you ask a follow-up question, in cases like this. For the solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to use `\scshape`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}    

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}  
  \node [circle, draw=red, fill=red!30] (N1) at (0,0) {A};
  \node [circle, draw=red, fill=green!30] (N2) at (5,0) {B};
  \draw [red,->] [postaction={decoration={raise=3pt, text along path, text={|\scshape|text},text align=center}, decorate}] (N1.north) to [out=45,in=135] (N2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit: answer to the updated version*

Put them into `{...}`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node [circle, draw=red, fill=red!30] (N1) at (0,0) {A}; 
\node [circle, draw=red, fill=green!30] (N2) at (5,0) {B}; 
\draw [red,->] [postaction={decoration={raise=3pt, text along path, text={|\scshape|text {\_ $\theta$}},text align=center}, decorate}] (N1.north) to [out=45,in=135] (N2.north); \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you make the updated version work?