# Why does TikZ add zeros?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is a code that computes the length of a line and attaches it to the line. So far, so good, but in math mode somehow additional zeros get appended to the distance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing}
\makeatletter 
\tikzset{%
 type/.code={\pgfextra{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\MyLen}{veclen(\the\pgf@pathmaxx-\the\pgf@pathminx,\the\pgf@pathmaxy-\the\pgf@pathminy)/28.45365}
 \global\xdef\NewLen{\MyLen}}}
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
dimstyle/.style={postaction={type,decorate,
   decoration={text along path,raise=2pt,
   text={$L=\NewLen$},text align=center}},
   },decoration={brace},decorate
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,4);

   \draw [dimstyle] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, if I replace in the above `text={$L=\NewLen$}` by `text={$L=$\NewLen}` (i.e. print in text rather than math mode), I get

[image]

**Question**: Where do the additional zeros come from?

Comment: Off-topic: I think that `\global\xdef` is redundant. As far as I understand `\xdef` is the short form of `\global\edef`, so `\global\xdef` would be `\global\global\edef`.

Comment: Why not just avoid it with `$L={}$\NewLen`

Comment: You want to see something **really** crazy, try `text={$L={\NewLen}$}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sure, I could avoid it like this, my question is why this happens. Note also that the code does not terminate if I put `\NewLen` in `\text{}`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I know, and our messages crossed.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, you're definitely right. Note, however, that removing the `\global` won't change the situation.

Comment: Check out `\pgfmathprintnumber` and `number format` starting on page 945 (section 92).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You want to see something really, **really** crazy, try `text={$L=\the\dimexpr\NewLen pt\relax$}`. This means that the additional zeros aren't a number truncation thing, but it's Ti*k*Z repeating the last character of the input string...

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks! That's certainly helpful, but it is not clear to me how this explains the feature. Notice that in math mode it will add enough digits to fill the available space, i.e. `\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (6,8);

   \draw [dimstyle] (A)--(B);` will give you much more digits.

Comment: @marmot It looks like Ti*k*Z is repeating the last character only if it is math mode. Try `text={$L=\NewLen$~}`. Very strange...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, further evidence can be obtained by making the distance longer like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417639/why-does-tikz-add-zeros?noredirect=1#comment1044354_417639).

Comment: You might experiment with `number format={assume math mode=true}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks again. Certainly your statements contain the key. Yet I'm lacking the full picture.

Comment: Just `text={$a$}` suffices to trigger the repetition. It has nothing to do with number printing.

Comment: I traced the problem to the file `texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.text.code.tex`. In there, the macro `\pgf@lib@dec@text@scanchar` scans the text recursively until it is `\pgfutil@empty` (which is an empty macro). The problem is that the text never gets emptied. Once the scanner reaches the second `$` it starts the scanning again. This is as far as I could go :(

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357919/121799) I found a related question, this great feature seems not to be limited to math mode nor to numbers.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Makes sense and most likely also explains [the feature here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357919/121799). So you can answer two questions at once ;-)

Comment: @marmot Yes, I checked and the process in `\pgf@lib@dec@text@scanchar` is the same for both questions. But I don't know *why* it happens, I just discovered *where*.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75256/how-to-insert-math-with-curly-brackets-into-tikz-decoration-text-along-path#comment160873_75257 Indeed, `text={$L=\NewLen${}}` avoids the repetition.

Comment: Note that you can also avoid it using `text effects along path`. `text along path` always does this: text, numbers, symbols, whatever. The example here is needlessly complex: most of the included elements are not needed to trigger the issue.

Comment: @cfr I am not disputing any of your statements. It is just that I was initially very surprised, and so were many others. And IMHO it is sort of an issue that might get fixed, nobody really needs these repetitions.

Comment: I don't know why it adds zeros (although I suppose I should). But I do know the manual states in the `text along path` decoration docs: "However, even modestly complex mathematical typesetting is unlikely to be successful along a path (or even desirable)."

Comment: @MarkWibrow Yes. But naively I would expect "However, even modestly complex mathematical typesetting is unlikely to be successful along a path (or even desirable)." to cause an error, and not this repetition. Please note also that this is not limited to mathematical expressions, as you can see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357919/121799) and to some extent also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75257/121799) . (Obviously, I was not aware of these posts when I submitted my question.) So there seems to be something on top of "Please don't do math here".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `pgflibrarydecorations.text.code.tex` line 274-277

> ```
> \def\pgf@lib@dec@text@endoftext{%
>   \let\pgfdecoraterestoftext\pgfutil@empty%
>   \let\pgf@lib@dec@text@char\pgfutil@empty%
> }
> ```

it should be
`\pgfdecorationrestoftext` instead of
`\pgfdecoraterestoftext`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\makeatletter
\def\pgf@lib@dec@text@endoftext{%
    \let\pgfdecorationrestoftext\pgfutil@empty%
    \let\pgf@lib@dec@text@char\pgfutil@empty%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (B) at (3,4);
   \draw[decorate,decoration={text along path,text={$abc$},text align=center}](A)--(B);
   \draw(A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Almost impossible to spot. (Not that I tried.) Thanks!!!!

Comment: sourceforge is currently down... If someone sees this remind me to report the bug. (or report it yourself.)

Comment: It seems like I cannot report the bug there (would probably need a sourceforge account, which I do not have).

Comment: Even with your solution I still get `abcc` instead of `abc` above the line ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvQD7.png)).  At least it is better than before with `abcccccccccccccccc`.

Comment: I did some research, `text={$abc}` will partially solve this.